# Can the PackageVersions element of the metadata be automatically updated

Tags: apex, deployment, app-development, metadata

I'm working on an application that consists of a base package and an extension package. Every time I update the base package in the development environment, I have to change the `<packageVersions>` element in the metadata of some of the classes in the extension, so they use the latest version. Is it possible to specify that a class always uses the latest version of a package?

**Update:** We don't really have a build process. I use Eclipse with the Force.com Perspective to develop the application and the extension. If a new version is released I use the standard Salesforce interface with a web browser (just via Setup -> Create -> Package -> etc..) After the new release is uploaded I install it in the development org for the extension. Maybe I would have to create an extra function in the install script that uses the metadata API to update the metadata of the org in which the package is installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the risk of proposing a very low-tech but low-effort solution, what about just a simple script that (in your local, recently sync'd Eclipse workspace) traverses all your relevant `*-meta.xml` files and does a simple string sed-like operation to bring them to your current version? Then you just do a top-level refresh in Eclipse, and all the files get uploaded that have been changed.

I know it's low-tech, and that using some custom code around the metadata API is the "correct" approach, but you use Eclipse without a build process so this seems like the most simple solution to a not very complicated problem.

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

With a little modification, you could use my Ruby script to walk the file system with my namespacing script and update the metadata of package components to update them.

The script is here: https://github.com/jordanbaucke/sfdc-namespace-prefix

Comment: What exactly does this script do? I'm not experienced with ruby, so if you can please explain in short?

Comment: So the script takes a file-path and walks all the files and does a glorified find-replace on the strings that are specified in a couple of text files. It would be good for specifying the version of the api that the related package is using before you install it. Although if the parent package is 'already installed' in the org, which in re-reading I think it is, you can't change that installed package version without re-uploading a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I will say that this is tentatively possible. But it will depend **alot** on your current build process.

The only way to achieve what you are suggesting is with the metadata api. You would need to push new versions of your *.cls-meta.xml files

One of the most common build tools for ISV's is Jenkins (This is what my company uses) and Jenkins is great for something like this.

This is where your build process matters. There are a number of libraries that you can use to invoke the metadata api, whatever you choose you will then need to integrate into your build process somehow. I understand this is not a complete answer but without further details there isn't much more I can suggest.

**Edit**
If you don't have an automatic build process, then you are free write something in the language of your choice and run it manually as another step of your manual build.

The first think I would do is, if you are a Salesforce ISV partner, ask to get major push upgrades enabled, this will make installing the package into your extension orgs **much** easier

Then you can run the script to update the classes (and presumably pages triggers etc).

The last consideration I would make is: Your process might be manual now, but if your business grows that might not be as feasible make sure the scripts you write can be integrated into some sort of automatic build process (reiterating Jenkins is great)

Comment: I updated my question, hope that helps. I will take a look at Jenkins, it could be useful.